# Why do coherent states of 1d SHO minimize uncertainty?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, coherent-states

If I define coherent states of the 1-d SHO to be eigenstates of the lowering operator, I know that these states minimize uncertainty.

I know the computations, but I was wondering if there was some deeper reason why lowering eigenstates necessarily minimize the uncertainty. Is there any such good reason or is this just a coincidence?